# Pairing pairs in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Using racket `cons` function I can pair two  numbers into one pair for example `(cons 1 2)` would return a pair `(1 . 2)`, but I can't use `cons` to make a pair of two pairs, `(cons (cons 1 2) (cons 3 4))` returns `((1 . 2) 3 . 4)`, what I want is `((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))`

How can I do such a thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two datums `((1 . 2) 3 . 4)` and `((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))` are exactly the same. So don't worry, you've got it right.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I tested that with `pair?` and `list?` functions and you're right it's a pair